# 302 response when redirecting to Stripe checkout URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, ruby-on-rails-7

In my Rails 7 application, I am working with a Subscription model and therefore am implementing subscriptions through the Stripe API.

See below the payment method (subscriptions_controller.rb) which is triggered when user clicks a 'choose plan' button. The redirection worked, then didn't work, then worked again; me not changing a thing about how the subscription is created and how I am retrieving the URL.

```
def payment
    @subscription = current_user.subscription
    if @subscription
      plan_id = params[:plan_id]
      @subscription.update(id: @subscription.id, plan_id:, user_id: current_user.id, active: true)
    else
      subscription_id = SecureRandom.uuid
      plan_id = params[:plan_id]
      @subscription = Subscription.new(id: subscription_id, plan_id:, user_id: current_user.id)
    end

    @checkout_session = create_checkout_session(@subscription)
    @subscription.checkout_session_id = @checkout_session.id
    @subscription.save!
    redirect_to @checkout_session.url, allow_other_host: true
  end

private

def create_checkout_session(subscription)
    Stripe::Checkout::Session.create({
      customer: current_user.stripe_id,
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      line_items: [{
        price: subscription.plan.stripe_price_id,
        quantity: 1
      }],
      mode: 'subscription',
      success_url: subscription_url(subscription),
      cancel_url: new_subscription_url
    })
  end
```

**Error messages**

- In my terminal, I receive a 302.
- The page shows:

> "Something went wrong. The page you were looking for could not be found. Please check the URL or contact the merchant."

- And the console throws:

> "CheckoutInitError: apiKey is not set".

Calling a raise before the redirection and taking the URL from there works. Taking the URL from the Stripe developer logs (meaning from the created checkout session) also works.

What is wrong with my redirect call?

I added a raise before the redirect_to call and checked whether the URLs are the same:

```
>> @checkout_session.url

"https://checkout.stripe.com/c/pay/cs_test_a1ayFdxprxmpwtZA9cyvECPG2bNaLnCN7e5UToqdr8oNrDxZKfm1BrFts9#fidkdWxOYHwnPyd1blpxYHZxWjA0SENmbjZOdzF0UWNqbkhndD1SY0l8TUxkR2B0fUZ9PH9MX0w2T05Bcz1Cb11taU1AcTxRQkhWTFZGdWo2Z1F1MXZJfENzcDdOYlxjM0NAV01nUlRsTkNDNTVLX0twf3FyQicpJ2N3amhWYHdzYHcnP3F3cGApJ2lkfGpwcVF8dWAnPyd2bGtiaWBabHFgaCcpJ2BrZGdpYFVpZGZgbWppYWB3dic%2FcXdwYHgl"


>> redirect_to @checkout_session.url, allow_other_host: true

"<html><body>You are being <a href=\"https://checkout.stripe.com/c/pay/cs_test_a1ayFdxprxmpwtZA9cyvECPG2bNaLnCN7e5UToqdr8oNrDxZKfm1BrFts9#fidkdWxOYHwnPyd1blpxYHZxWjA0SENmbjZOdzF0UWNqbkhndD1SY0l8TUxkR2B0fUZ9PH9MX0w2T05Bcz1Cb11taU1AcTxRQkhWTFZGdWo2Z1F1MXZJfENzcDdOYlxjM0NAV01nUlRsTkNDNTVLX0twf3FyQicpJ2N3amhWYHdzYHcnP3F3cGApJ2lkfGpwcVF8dWAnPyd2bGtiaWBabHFgaCcpJ2BrZGdpYFVpZGZgbWppYWB3dic%2FcXdwYHgl\">redirected</a>.</body></html>"
```

The first one works, the second one (the one it is redirected to) has a backslash at the end (which you can't even see when I post it in here). If I take it off and refresh, it works. Why is this added and how can I remove it?

Comment: When you get the "Something went wrong. The page you were looking for could not be found. Please check the URL or contact the merchant." error, I recommend copying the url from the address bar of the browser and pasting it somewhere like a text editor. Then, I recommend copying the url from that checkout session from the Stripe developer logs and pasting it below the one you grabbed from the browser. Are they the same?

Comment: Hi @codename_duchess. Thanks for the input, I did and updated the question. It adds a backslash to the url and if I remove it, I get through to Stripe.

Comment: Can you show your routes please?   At least the ones relevant to the above code.  I have setup stripe checkout a few times now so I should be able to help you out with this.  on this line:  redirect_to @checkout_session.url, allow_other_host: true   have you tried using the route helper instead so redirect_to checkout_session_url_path for example?  When you use a route helper Rails does some behind the scenes "magic" to encode the URL properly.

Comment: the checkout_session.url is not inside my routes though. it is the url that the stripe checkout session object produces. i am calling .url on the checkout_session variable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was just running into this exact issue today and found the problem. It looks like Turbo is messing with the redirect.

I was able to fix it by simply adding `data: { turbo: false }` to the link to the payment route which redirects to Stripe.

Comment: Saved my day, thnx

Comment: Omg, it did work! Thank you so much, you saved the financial future of my app.

Comment: Unreal, what a pain, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had this same error (i.e., the `CheckoutInitError: apiKey is not set`) with the JavaScript Fetch API, and it turned out that the problem was that the redirect URL was being visited twice, once by the `redirect: follow`, and another time by `window.location.href = response.url`. I fixed it by replacing the `fetch` request with an HTML Form.

Comment: Thanks for putting this out here for people like me, who can benefit from this! Cheers.

Comment: Thanks so much for this input, sounds very promising. I am currently not working on this issue, but as soon as I will get back to it, I will check it out and accept it as the answer if it works.

Comment: Ding ding ding!!! You're life saver!!