# Rails redirect_to with Stripe Session URL Truncates at # Character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm encountering a peculiar issue in my Rails application when trying to redirect a user to a Stripe Checkout session URL using the redirect_to method. The redirection fails to navigate to the correct Stripe URL, seemingly truncating the URL at a # character, although the # doesn't visibly appear in the debugged URL. This issue occurs only in a specific method for resuming subscriptions, whereas initial subscription creation and redirection work as expected.

Context:

- Ruby 3.2.2
- Rails 7.0.6
- Stripe Checkout is used to generate a session for subscription resumption.
- The issue manifests as a redirection error with the message "Something went wrong" from Stripe's end, indicating a possible malformed URL or redirection issue.
- Manual copying and navigation using the logged session.url work correctly, suggesting the URL is correctly generated.

**First Method (Working as Expected):**

```
def create
  # Stripe customer creation and session initiation
  def create
    user_id = params[:user_id]
    user_full_name = params[:user_full_name]
    user_email = params[:user_email]

    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      name: user_full_name,
      email: user_email,
      description: "Customer id: #{user_id}",
      )

    session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create(
      customer: customer,
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      line_items: [{
                     price: 'price_1OrRAA',
                     quantity: 1,
                   }],
      mode: 'subscription',
      success_url: success_url + "?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
      cancel_url: cancel_url
    )
   redirect_to session.url, allow_other_host: true
end
```

**Second Method (Issue Occurs Here):**

```
def resume
    customer_id = current_user.subscriptions.first.customer_id

    session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create(
      customer: customer_id,
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      line_items: [{
                     price: 'price_1OrRAA',
                     quantity: 1,
                   }],
      mode: 'subscription',
      success_url: subscription_update_success_url + "?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
      cancel_url: subscription_update_fail_url
    )

    Rails.logger.debug "Redirecting to: #{session.url}"

    redirect_to session.url, allow_other_host: true
  end
```

**Troubleshooting Done:**

- Confirmed the session.url is correct via Rails.logger.debug.
- The issue persists even when ensuring URL is correctly formed and not manipulated.
- No apparent difference in URL handling between the working and non-working methods.

**Questions:**

- Why might redirect_to behave differently in the second method, given similar usage in both cases?
- Are there known issues or nuances with Rails redirect_to that could cause URL truncation or alteration, particularly concerning external URLs like those generated by Stripe?
- Any suggestions on how to diagnose or resolve this redirection issue?

Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The first method does not redirect

Comment: Yeah, why does your first method not have any redirect-related code? Are you handling that redirect client-side or was it a bad copy-paste?

Comment: yeah, I've missed to copy and past the last line - it is `redirect_to session.url, allow_other_host: true`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Turbo is messing up the URL for a redirect. Adding `data: { turbo: false }` to the link where this controller method is requested healths the issue.  Thank you @andrew-katz for the answer in [302 response when redirecting to Stripe checkout URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76254891/302-response-when-redirecting-to-stripe-checkout-url) !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  If you identified an answer on another question that solved your issue, that usually means that your question is a duplicate and should be closed.  There's nothing at all wrong with that, and duplicate questions can be useful signposts to point future searches to the canonical answer.  This allows us to have one question that collects the answers, as there may be more than one good answer, and the best solution may change in the future.